# Is there a way to run a website in full screen in Windows?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Is there a way to run a website in full screen in Windows? I'm running a Webpage which is only a form and it's running on a kiosk in a shopping mall.

I want this page to display in full screen. no other things should be seen on screen except the webpage and user should not be able to close the webpage using the **X** button.

Just like an ATM Machine.

Comment: I assume pressing F11 isn't an option?

Comment: This is a browser / operating system issue, but has nothing to do with JavaScript etc.

Comment: but many user know's the F11. I want to lock the screen and nothing should work like Alt+tab

Comment: Is a windows app with a browser container an option?

Comment: Duplicate, perhaps? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6279792/web-browsers-into-kiosk-mode

Comment: @Tim - and when I take my mouse at top Chrome give indication to exit full screen http://min.us/mB8QqsRp3

Answer (score 4):

Most browsers offer a kiosk mode that does exactly this. Search for example "internet explorer kiosk mode" or "chrome kiosk mode" depending on which browser you will be using.

If you can't find it, then normally the F11 makes a web page fullscreen, but it's not as good a kiosk mode (won't disable screensaver or lock from using other softwares)

Comment: when I take my mouse at top Chrome give indication to exit full screen min.us/mB8QqsRp3

Comment: Is this using Chrome kiosk mode or simply using fullscreen mode? In Kiosk mode, I believe chrome never shows that indication. To start Chrome in kiosk mode you need to use Chrome.exe --kiosk in a command line.

Answer (score 2):

Press <kbd>F11</kbd> to get full screen

Comment: Do you mean F11?

Comment: Cheers, I caught the mistake too,

Comment: Pressing F11 again though would allow the user to press the X to close the page, this wouldn't lock it down so the user couldn't close it.

Answer (score 2):

I think Kiosk mode is what you would want. Check out this page:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/154780

Also do a quick Google search and you'll find more. I think you can have IE default to start in Kiosk mode.

Answer (score 2):

Try Internet Explorer's Kiosk mode

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/154780

It runs full screen with no GUI around the webpage, and less ways to easily exit.
Just run `iexplore -k [website]` from the run dialog.

Answer (score 1):

Press F11 within your browser.

Firefox and Chrome have supported this for as long as I can remember. IE8 and IE9 do too, but I'm unsure about earlier versions.

Answer (score 1):

```
window.open("mypage.html","fullscreen=yes")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve a similar effect through JavaScript, by doing something like this:

```
maximizeWindow = function() {
    window.moveTo(0, 0);
    window.resizeTo(screen.availWidth, screen.availHeight);
}
```

It won't really be fullscreen, but it will resize the window to fullscreen dimensions.